# How to make a nested loop to make a Chessboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, nested

Hey guys i'm new to JS and i'd like to learn this language, but there is one thing i'm stuck with , that is making the nested loop work so I can make a chessboard game appear. this is what I got so far :

```
while (y <= 7) {
  if (y % 2 == 0) {
    document.write("<div class=sq2> </div>")
      ++y;
  } else {
    document.write("<div class=sq1> </div>")
      ++y;
  }
}
```

sq1 makes a white tile
sq2 makes a black tile.
each row they should be diffrent ,thats why Ive got the IF statement.
This makes 1 row from left to right perfectly.
But i can't seem to make the nested loop work so that it makes 8 rows from top to bottom. This is what I had :

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

while (x <= 8) {
  while (y <= 7) {
    if (y % 2 == 0) {
      document.write("<div class=sq2> </div>")
        ++y;
    } else {
      document.write("<div class=sq1> </div>")
        ++y;
    }
  }
  ++x;
}
```

Thanks

TheOne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of this will be done through CSS, namely you have to tell each div to not take up an entire line (display: inline-block) and give them a width and height:

```
.sq1 {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
.sq2 {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You'll want to add some kind of break (you can use the "br" tag but there are other ways as well) each time the 'x' loop restarts so that subsequent rows can be made.

You'll also need to reset y to

```
var x = 0;

// declare y here since there is no "block scope" prior to es6.
var y;

// stop at 7 since you are starting at 0.
while (x <= 7) {
  // reset y to 0 each time the 'x' loop restarts.
  y = 0;

  // add a break dom node to create each new row.
  document.write('<br/>');

  while (y <= 7) {
    if (y % 2 == 0) {
      // classes should be in quotes.
      document.write('<div class="sq2"></div>');
    } else {
      document.write('<div class="sq1""></div>');
    }

    // you only need to include this once since both paths of the if-conditional were calling it.
    ++y;
  }
  ++x;
}
```

This will give you 8 rows of alternating colored squares, BUT each row will be exactly the same. You now need to account for the fact that every other row starts with an alternate color. To do this you can use the fact that `% 2` will only ever return 0 or 1 and take the modulus of y plus x. This for the first row this will give 0 + 0 = 0 => "sq2" for the first square and 1 + 0 = 1 => "sq1" for the first square of the second row.

```
 if ((y + x) % 2 == 0) {...}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/gayupo/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thanks! this was by far the most useful comment for my situation! but the only thing i have proube with , is that I don't know where to place the ' if ((y + x) % 2 == 0) {...} ' statement , is it supposed to be in the while 'x' loop? , also , i use 'float : left ' , does this affect this code ? 
Thanks!

Comment: You would use that instead of the current if-conditional you are using inside of your 'y' loop. Yes, applying 'float' will affect the code. Any CSS you add could affect how it renders. See this [updated example](http://jsbin.com/gayupo/3/edit?html,output) which uses 'float' and 'clear' CSS attributes to remove the spacing between lines.

Answer (score 1):

I used a `<table>` (yes I am fully aware that using a `<table>` makes kittens cry). The chess pieces are generated at load time along with the `#chessBoard`. They comprise of a group of font symbols, each representing a black or white chess piece. Details are commented in the source. The source is available on <kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/gAIV3ButneLU1gvPg5Rg/)</kbd> and a Snippet.

#### Snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    /* BOARD */
    /* 
    || Despite what everyone says not to use the <table> for
    || layout purposes, I'm doing it anyway. The display:
    || table-* properties are useful but takes too much effort 
    || to use on larger projects.
    */
    
    table#ChessBoard {
      width: 420px;
      height: 420px;
      table-layout: fixed;
      border: 3px ridge gray;
      border-collapse: separate;
      border-spacing: 2px;
    }
    
    tr.rank {
      width: 420px;
      height: 45px;
    }
    
    td.cell {
      width: 45px;
      height: 45px;
      border-left: 1px solid red;
      border-right: 1px solid red;
      border-top: 1px solid blue;
      border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    }
    
    .white {
      background: white;
      color: red;
    }
    
    .black {
      background: black;
      color: blue;
    }
    /* This is a number/letter in the top left corner of 
    || every cell.
    */
    
    sup {
      text-align: left;
      vertical-align: top;
      font-size: 8px;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-family: Verdana;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      line-height: .3
    }
    /* PIECES */
    /*
    || This is the common styles for a game piece
    */
    
    div.piece.piece {
      max-width: 45px;
      max-height: 45px;
      font-size: 35px;
      font-weight: 100;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      display: block;
      line-height: .3;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: transparent;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    /*~~~~~~~~~~< PIECES >~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
    /* These classes each have a unicode of a chess piece
    || in the content of an :after pseudo-element.
    */
    
    .wK:after {
      content: '\2654';
    }
    
    .wQ:after {
      content: '\2655';
    }
    
    .wR:after {
      content: '\2656';
    }
    
    .wB:after {
      content: '\2657';
    }
    
    .wN:after {
      content: '\2658';
    }
    
    .wP:after {
      content: '\2659';
    }
    
    .bK:after {
      content: '\265a';
    }
    
    .bQ:after {
      content: '\265b';
    }
    
    .bR:after {
      content: '\265c';
    }
    
    .bB:after {
      content: '\265d';
    }
    
    .bN:after {
      content: '\265e';
    }
    
    .bP:after {
      content: '\265f';
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="chessBoard"></table>

  <script>
    /* BOARD */
    var brd = document.getElementById("chessBoard");
    /*
    || 4 Arrays that have the initial position of each chess piece
    || pre-arranged.
    */
    var black = ['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'];
    var bPawn = ['bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP'];

    var white = ['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR'];
    var wPawn = ['wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP'];

    // First a rank (a row on a chessboard) must be made
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

      var rank = brd.insertRow(i);
      rank.classList.add('rank');
      rank.id = 8 - i;

      for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        /*
        || On every iteration, a <td> is inserted...
        || ...then it's colors are given if it's odd/even.
        */
        var cell = rank.insertCell(j);
        var color = parseInt((i + j) % 2, 10) === 0 ? 'white' : 'black';
        /* The array is for establishing a horizontal guide for
        || the chessboard. 
        || The <sup> is for that previously mentioned feature 
        || of coordinates on each square.
        || The cell is further prepared with classes, id, etc.
        || The last line of this block calls a function
        || called pieces.
        */
        var col = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'];
        var coord = document.createElement('sup');
        coord.textContent = parseInt(8 - i, 10) + col[j];
        cell.appendChild(coord);
        cell.classList.add('cell');
        cell.classList.add(color);
        pieces(i);
      }
    }
    /* pieces will:
    || check to see of we are on the 2 ranks for each side.
    || If so, then it determines which rank of pieces needs
    || to be created.
    */
    function pieces(i) {
      var row = brd.rows[i].querySelectorAll('td');
      var piece = document.createElement('div');
      piece.setAttribute('draggable', true);
      switch (i) {
        case 0:
          piece.classList.add('piece');
          piece.classList.add('black');
          piece.classList.add(black[j]);
          cell.appendChild(piece);
          break;
        case 1:
          piece.classList.add('piece');
          piece.classList.add('black');
          piece.classList.add('wP');
          cell.appendChild(piece);
          break;
        case 6:
          piece.classList.add('piece');
          piece.classList.add('white');
          piece.classList.add('bP');
          cell.appendChild(piece);
          break;
        case 7:
          piece.classList.add('piece');
          piece.classList.add('white');
          piece.classList.add(white[j]);
          cell.appendChild(piece);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
    /* This is a group of drag and drop functions that are not          
    || finished but it's a good start should you decide that drag
    || and drop is needed.
    is 
    function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);
    }

    function dropHandler(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");

      if (id == "srcMove" && ev.target.id == "destMove") {
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getAttribute(id));
      }
    }
  */
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The CSS isn't the best (I hate CSS). So the CSS is your problem!

```js
var board = document.getElementById("board");  // get the board element

for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {                   // to create rows
  var row = document.createElement("div");     // create this row
  for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {                 // to create cells
    var cell = document.createElement("div");  // create this cell
    if(i % 2 == j % 2)                         // do the math
      cell.className = "white";
    else
      cell.className = "black";
    row.appendChild(cell);                     // add this cell to the row
  }
  board.appendChild(row);                      // add this row to the board
}
```

```css
#board > div {
  height: 20px;
}

.white, .black {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset y, so that the inner loop executes again after the first iteration of the outer loop.

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

while (x <= 8) {
    while (y <= 7) {
        if (y % 2 == 0) {
            document.write("<div class=sq2> </div>")
            ++y;
        }
        else {
            document.write("<div class=sq1> </div>")
            ++y;
       }
   }
   y = 0;
   ++x;
}
```